# How can i remove HTML nbsp tags from select options when assigning the text of option to hidden input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When the value is assigned to html hidden element it also assign nbsp tag which is in select statement. I don't want any html tags just only text

```js
function setTextFieldA(ddl) {
  var a = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].text; 
  var res = a.slice(0,12);
  alert(res);
  document.getElementById('prod1').value = res;
  /*document.getElementById('prod1').value = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].text;*/
}
```

```html
<select name="1" id="1" class="selectadd" onchange="setTextFieldA(this)" required >
 <option value="99">Red Vein         </option>
 <option value="99">White Vein       </option>
 <option value="99">Green Vein             </option>
 <option value="109">Red Horned  &nbsp; [Add $10]</option>
 <option value="109">White Horned [Add $10]</option>
 <option value="109">Green Horned [Add $10]</option>
 <option value="109">Maeng da &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; [Add $10]</option>
</select>
<input id="prod1" type = "hidden" name = "prod1" value = "Red Vein" />
```

Comment: Please clarify, questions like this will get you downvoted

Comment: @poly Please have a look. pls help me

Comment: So you want to remove the `&nbsp;` from option values, example: `<option value="109">Red Horned  &nbsp; [Add $10]</option>`. Did I get it right?

Comment: No i just want to remove "&nbsp;" tag when the values is assigned to hidden type input by javascript . During form submit post request value of prod1 should not contain "&nbsp;" just the product name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use jQuery:

```
function setTextFieldA(ddl) {
  var res = $('option:selected',ddl).text().slice(0,12).trim();
  alert(res);
  $('#prod1').val(res);
}
```

Check this **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6q3tkxwk/)**

Answer (score 0):

First, do not use slice, you never know what length your value may be.
Remove `var res = a.slice(0,12);`

Second, you can use regular expression to remove all white spaces and the price tag at the end of the string, like this:

```
var res = res.replace(/\s*(\[.*\])*$/, ""); //removes white spaces and "[Add 10$]" tag
```